# How to put buttons next to each other?

Tags: html

I have a table and put 2 buttons in the last column, but they are one below each other. It looks as following:

[image]

The HTML code look as following:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 80%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>EMail</th>
                <th>CompanyName</th>
                <th>JobTitle</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Avatar</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in contacts">
                <td>{{item.Id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Gender}}</td>
                <td>{{item.FirstName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.LastName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.EMail}}</td>
                <td>{{item.CompanyName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.JobTitle}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Phone}}</td>
                <td><img src="{{ item.Avatar }}" /></td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-model="$scope.Contact" ng-click="edit(contacts[$index])" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                    <button ng-click="delete($index)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I've tried a lot of settings, but it doesn't help.

How to put them next to each other?

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: You can use css display inline block to achieve

Comment: You should add the tag of the template engine and of eventually of the CSS framework (or simply CSS) you're using.

Comment: Where should I put inline? display: inline-block; doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy problem to fix.

As you used tables in your structure, you can use tables in the last column.

Inside that last column `td`, add a table. The table body should look like this.

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 80%;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th>EMail</th>
        <th>CompanyName</th>
        <th>JobTitle</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Avatar</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in contacts">
        <td>{{item.Id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Gender}}</td>
        <td>{{item.FirstName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.LastName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.EMail}}</td>
        <td>{{item.CompanyName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.JobTitle}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Phone}}</td>
        <td>
          <img src="{{ item.Avatar }}" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <button ng-model="$scope.Contact" ng-click="edit(contacts[$index])" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button ng-click="delete($index)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: This table format might not be right layout, but it provides sufficient and a correct answer.

Comment: It works, but there's some strange line above buttons. Please, take a look at post's update. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: If we want to get rid of line above, we need to add: style="border-top-width: 0px;" in <td> elements that surround buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code and achieve

```
<button ng-model="$scope.Contact" ng-click="edit(contacts[$index])" class="btn btn-primary" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">Edit</button>
<button ng-click="delete($index)" class="btn btn-primary" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">Delete</button>
```

Or if you use Bootstrap then you can get Bootstrap Code from [Bootstrap Group Buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) or use below code

```
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Middle</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

to achieve

Comment: It doesn't provide the to separate buttons like the OP requested but I ended up going with this btn-group route.

Answer (score 0):

in stylesheet make button css display to inline or inline-block
Also do check the TD width and buttons width. If the buttons width is greater than the TD width it will break to next row for sure

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="list-unstyled list-inline"><button ng-model="$scope.Contact" ng-click="edit(contacts[$index])" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button><button ng-click="delete($index)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you were looking for is a button group.

```
   <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                            <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#editModal">Edit
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" id="delete">Delete
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```